# Show all outgoing relationships with cypher for nodes that have more than 1 relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship

I currently have a graph database that has 2 node labels and 1 relationship type.

If i run

```
MATCH (u)-[r]->(n) return u, n
```

I can see everything. Some nodes have multiple outgoing relationships. I'd like to filter this view for where nodes have 2 or more outgoing relationships. I tried

```
MATCH (u)-[r]->(n) with count(r) as c,u,n  where c > 1 return u, n
```

But this gives me no results. I've seen some answers on here that return just a node, but I want the 2 nodes and the relationship shown. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDITED]

This should work:

```
MATCH (u)-->(n)
WITH u, COLLECT(n) AS ns
WHERE SIZE(ns) > 1
RETURN u, ns
```

If you specify a set of "grouping keys" with an [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/) like `COLLECT()` (in the above query, `u` is the sole grouping key), then the aggregation is performed over that set of keys.

So, in the above query, `COLLECT(n)` is collecting al the `n` nodes for the same `u` node.

Comment: Thank you, however I received the following error, which I would guess is due to the comma in the where statement?

Comment: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input ',': expected an identifier character, whitespace, '{', node labels, a property map, a relationship pattern, '.', '(', '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR, LOAD CSV, FROM, INTO, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE GRAPH >>, CREATE >> GRAPH, CREATE GRAPH, CREATE, SET, DELETE GRAPHS, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, CALL, PERSIST, RELOCATE, RETURN, SNAPSHOT, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 2, column 8 (offset: 23))
"WHERE u, COUNT(*) > 1"

Comment: I should have tested before I sent. My answer has been fixed.